# ThreeJS: How to import PositionalAudioHelper?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to import the PositionalAudioHelper. The code is very basic:

```
// create the PositionalAudio object (passing in the listener)
import * as THREE from 'three';

var sound = new THREE.PositionalAudio( listener );
var helper = new THREE.PositionalAudioHelper(sound);
sound.add( helper );
```

The webpack error I get is:

```
"export 'PositionalAudioHelper' (imported as 'THREE') was not found in 'three'
```

I installed Three using `yarn` so it may not install the latest version that includes this commit: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15748

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `PositionalAudioHelper` is located on the `examples` directoy, you have to import it like so:

```js
import { PositionalAudioHelper } from 'three/examples/jsm/helpers/PositionalAudioHelper.js';
```

`three.js R116`

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks!